# Azure B2C cannot access graph api

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I got an access token to fetch the graph client using the following code:

```
    string graphResourceID = "https://graph.windows.net";      
    string tenantID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Domain"];
    string aadInstance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantID + 
    "/oauth2/v2.0/token";

Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential credential = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(aadInstance);
authenticationContext.TokenCache.Clear();

var authResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(graphResourceID,clientcred);
```

And then tried to use the token to fetch the signed in User's info via the AD graph api:

```
Uri servicePointUri = new Uri(graphResourceID);
Uri serviceRoot = new Uri(servicePointUri, tenantID);
ActiveDirectoryClient activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(serviceRoot,async () => await GetTokenForApplication());    
var result = await activeDirectoryClient.Users.Where(u => u.ObjectId.Equals(userObjectID)).ExecuteAsync();
IUser user = result.CurrentPage.ToList().First();

return View(user);
```

However, this returns the following error:

```
"error": {
"code": "Authorization_IdentityNotFound",
"message": "The identity of the calling application could not be established.",
"innerError": {
"request-id": "2bdae8ff-d935-4e01-80a1-78cbc8acf4de",
"date": "2017-08-09T18:07:40"
```

I made sure that mu B2C application has the "Read and Write Directory Data" permission for Windows Active Directory :

[image]

Can anyone please help? Been stuck on this for a while. TIA

**Edit**

I also tried using Microsoft.Graph but end up getting the same error. Plus for B2C users I think it's best if we stick to Azure Ad Graph api for now: https://dev.office.com/blogs/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys it seems I was using the tenant ID of the original directory I used to create my B2C directory. Hence the code could not find my application. I have to use the tenant ID/domain name of my Azure B2C directory where the B2C app is registered by clicking on switch directory in the upper right corner of the portal.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you use the Azure AD library to operate Graph API. I recommand that you could use [Microsoft.Graph](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph) to do that. Please also set the permission with Microsoft Graph.

**Note**: don't forget to click [**Grant Permissions**] button.

[image]

The following is the demo code.

```
string graphResourceId = "https://graph.microsoft.com/";
string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}";
string tenantId = "tenantId";
string clientId = "client Id";
string secretKey = "secret key"
var accessToken = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(graphResourceId, new ClientCredential(clientId,secret)).Result.AccessToken;
var graphserviceClient = new GraphServiceClient(
                new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                    requestMessage =>
                    {
                        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);

                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }));
var user = graphserviceClient.Users.Request().GetAsync().Result.FirstOrDefault();
```

**Test Result:**

[image]

**Update:**

I also test with Azure AD graph API with Azure B2c, it also works correctly on my side. I also assign the [Read and write directory data] and click [Grant permissions] without other permission setting.

The following is the demo code I used for test.

```
 string graphResourceID = "https://graph.windows.net";
 string tenantID = "tenant Id";
 Uri servicePointUri = new Uri(graphResourceID);
 Uri serviceRoot = new Uri(servicePointUri, tenantID);
 ActiveDirectoryClient activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(serviceRoot, async () => await GetAppTokenAsync());
 var result =  activeDirectoryClient.Users.ExecuteAsync().Result;
 IUser user = result.CurrentPage.ToList().First();



 private static async Task<string> GetAppTokenAsync()
 {
        string graphResourceID = "https://graph.windows.net";
        string tenantID = "tenant id ";
        //please remove v2 from the link
        string aadInstance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantID +"/oauth2/token";
        var clientId = "client Id";
        var appKey = "secret key";
        // Instantiate an AuthenticationContext for my directory (see authString above).
        AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(aadInstance, false);
        // Create a ClientCredential that will be used for authentication.
        // This is where the Client ID and Key/Secret from the Azure Management Portal is used.
        ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
        // Acquire an access token from Azure AD to access the Azure AD Graph (the resource)
        // using the Client ID and Key/Secret as credentials.
        AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(graphResourceID, clientCred); 
        // Return the access token.
        return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
   }
```

**Test Result:**

[image]

If it still doesn't work for you. I suggest you create a new Azure AD application and try it again.

**Packages.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient" version="2.1.1" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.6.4" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.6.4" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" version="5.6.4" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" version="3.19.8" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.6.4" targetFramework="net471" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer Tom, but I already tried that and made sure that Microsoft.Graph has the Read and Write directory data permission. It works for my non B2C azure web app but for my B2C web app it gives the same error:"error": { "code": "Authorization_IdentityNotFound", "message": "The identity of the calling application could not be established.", "innerError": { "request-id": "2bdae8ff-d935-4e01-80a1-78cbc8acf4de", "date": "2017-08-09T18:07:40" Is there any special permission/setting that I need to do to access the graph api via a B2C web application

Comment: I also test with B2C Azure AD web application, both ADAL and Microsoft Graph are working well. No other permission setting. I also update  the answer with ADAL code. If it still doesn't work for you, I suggest you create a new Azure AD application and try it again.